# Passing an array to a childNode

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript for SharePoint based on information provided at http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com. The problem is this was designed for one SharePoint list column and I need it to work for seven columns. I'm assuming to make this work I need to make colDueDate an array. Can someone help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

var colDueDate = 3;//single column 

var i=0; 
d=new Date(); //current date/time 
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD") // find all of the TDs 
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) 
{ 
if (x[i].className=="ms-vb2") //find the TDs styled for lists 
{ 
    if (Date.parse(x[i].parentNode.childNodes[colDueDate].childNodes[0].innerHTML)<d.getTime() ) 
    { 
        x[i].parentNode.childNodes[colDueDate].style.backgroundColor='red'; // set the color 
         } 
  } 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

blind flight:

```
var
colDueDate = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7...],
j = 0, i = 0,
tr, td, c,
d = new Date(),
x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 

  if (x[i].className == "ms-vb2") {
    tr = x[i].parentNode;

    for (j = 0; j < colDueDate.length; j++) {
      td = tr.childNodes[colDueDate[j]];
      c = td.childNodes[0];

      if (Date.parse(c.innerHTML) < d.getTime()) { 
        p.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Using your suggestion greatly helped put me in the right direction. for (j=0;j<colDueDate.length;j++)
{
tr=x[i].parentNode.childNodes[colDueDate[j]];
if (Date.parse(tr.childNodes[0].innerHTML)<d.getTime() ) 
        { 
        tr.style.backgroundColor='red';
        }
      }